# How to delete object from Firebase with listView onItemClick

Tags: java, listview, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a Shopping List application based on Firebase Realtime Database.

```
public class testActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Firebase
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

//Android Layout
private ListView productList;
private Button btnAdd;
private EditText etProduct;

//Array List
private ArrayList<String> productArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    //Firebase Reference
    String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(currentUserId);

    //ListView adapter
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, productArrayList);

    //Layout
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddProduct);
    etProduct = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddProduct);
    productList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.testList);
    productList.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDatabase.push().setValue(etProduct.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    productList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
             ----------- STUCK HERE ------------
        }
    });

    mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String product = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            productArrayList.add(product);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(testActivity.this, product + " added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String product = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            productArrayList.remove(product);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(testActivity.this, product + " removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

So, what it does - it takes currently logged in user unique ID and adds items from Edit Text to List View and to database with unique key. As it seems to work with saving to data base and reacts if I'm deleting it or adding in database.
I have created a OnClickEventListener for my list view, but I have no idea how to **delete currently clicked** item of listView from database and from a list view.

[Data structure in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9O9A.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use `delete()` method directly on that reference? In a meanwhile, if you want to create a shopping list app, I recommend you see this: **[Shopping List App Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** in which I explain step by step how to create a shopping list app from scratch.

Comment: Thank you Alex, your tutorial was something I was looking for!

Comment: Happy to hear that. If you have questions regarding the code, don't hesitate to leave a commnet. If you think that my tutorial is helpuf, please subscribe my channel. Thanks!